# Recompile Linux Kernel not to use specific CPU register

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu-registers, perf

I'm doing an experiment that write the index of loop into a CPU register R11, then building it with `gcc -ffixed-r11` try to let compiler know do not use that reg, and finally using perf to measure it.

But when I check the report (using `perf script`), the R11 value of most record entry is not what I expected, it supposed to be the number sequence like 1..2..3 or 1..4..7, etc. But actually it just a few fixed value. (possibly affected by system call overwriting?)

How can I let perf records the value I set to the register in my program? Or I must to recompile the whole kernel with `-ffixed-r11` to achieve?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Depending on the calling conventions used, it may not even be possible to recompile the kernel to not use R11 without breaking something. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I want to using records of perf to know how often (and exactly occurred in which number of loops) will my program trigger perf events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not try to recompile kernel when you just want to sample some register with perf. As I understand, kernel has its own set of registers and will not overwrite user R11. `syscall` interface uses some fixed registers which can't be changed (can you try different reg?) and there are often glibc gateways to syscall which may use some additional registers (they are not in kernel, they are user-space code; often generated or written in assembler). You may try using gdb to monitor the register to change to find who did it. It can do this (hmm, one more link to the same user on SO): [gdb: breakpoint when register will have value 0xffaa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223425/gdb-breakpoint-when-register-will-have-value-0xffaa) like `gdb ./program` then gdb commands `start; watch $r11; continue; where`.

Two weeks age there was question [perf-report show value of CPU register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163079/) about register value sampling with perf:

> I follow [this document](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-record.txt) and using `perf record` with `--intr-regs=ax,bx,r15`, trying to log additional CPU register information with PEBS record.

While there was x86 & PEBS, ARM may have  `--intr-regs` implemented too. Check output of `perf record --intr-regs=\?` ([man perf-record](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-record.txt): "To list the available registers use `--intr-regs=\?`") to find support status and register names.

To print registers, use `perf script -F ip,sym,iregs` command. There was example in some linux commits:

```
  # perf record --intr-regs=AX,SP usleep 1
  [ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
  [ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.016 MB perf.data (8 samples) ]
  # perf script -F ip,sym,iregs | tail -5
   ffffffff8105f42a native_write_msr_safe   AX:0xf    SP:0xffff8802629c3c00
   ffffffff8105f42a native_write_msr_safe   AX:0xf    SP:0xffff8802629c3c00
   ffffffff81761ac0 _raw_spin_lock   AX:0xffff8801bfcf8020    SP:0xffff8802629c3ce8
   ffffffff81202bf8 __vma_adjust_trans_huge   AX:0x7ffc75200000    SP:0xffff8802629c3b30
   ffffffff8122b089 dput   AX:0x101    SP:0xffff8802629c3c78
  #
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need cycle accurate profile of to the metal CPU activity then perf is not the right tool, as it is at best an approximation due to the fact it only samples the program at select points. See [this video on perf by Clang developer Chandler Carruth](https://youtu.be/nXaxk27zwlk).

Instead, you should single step through the program in order to monitor exactly what is happening to the registers. Or you could program your system bare metal without an OS, but that is probably outside the scope here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk "CppCon 2015: Chandler Carruth "Tuning C++: Benchmarks, and CPUs, and Compilers! Oh My!"" video is interesting, thanks! But how can it help to find register values?

Comment: @osgx it doesn't help, which is precisely my point. Perf only samples the registers at certain intervals so you will inevitably miss a lot of stuff that goes on in between.